# if files mtime is less than x amount. print those files

Tags: python

I am able to print mtime attribute of files. I am only concerned with files modified in say the last xxxx amount of minutes. I touched files in the directory so i know there are new files there.

```
file_list_attr = sftp.listdir_attr('/path')
fdir = sftp.listdir(path=source)

for f in file_list_attr:
    print "name=%s, modified date=%s, size=%s" % (f.filename, f.st_mtime,f.st_size)

mt = f.st_mtime
now=dt.datetime.now()
while f.st_mtime == now-dt.timedelta(minutes=2120):
   print 'You have something here'
else:
    print 'nada'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in how you check the mtime.

Shouldn't this line:

```
while f.st_mtime == now-dt.timedelta(minutes=2120):
```

be like:

```
while f.st_mtime > now-dt.timedelta(minutes=2120):
```

Or better:

```
delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=2120)
while f.st_mtime > dt.datetime.now() - delta:
    # ...
```

Because if you don't recalc your now-date I don't see the point of looping.

Comment: Poggi, I will give it a try. Thanks for helping a newbie

Comment: The issue seems to be is that datetime now can not iterate over an int. TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int